# Casting from IEnumerable to IEnumerator

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

I'm playing with `IEnumerable/<T>` and `IEnumerator/<T>`. In one of my trials, I tried to assign a returned value of type `IEnumerable<T>` to a value of `IEnumerator<T>` by using casting, and then trying to execute `MoveNext()` and `Current`. Though the casting issued no errors, I got no output:

```
class Animal
{
    public string AnimalType { get; set; }
    public Animal(string animal_type)
    {
        AnimalType = animal_type;
    }
}

class FarmCollection
{
    readonly Animal[] _farm = 
          { new Animal("duck"), new Animal("cow"), new Animal("sheep") };

    public IEnumerable<Animal> GetEnumerable()
    {
        foreach (Animal a in _farm)
            yield return a;
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        FarmCollection farm = new FarCollection();
        IEnumerator<Animal> enumerator = (IEnumerator<Animal>)farm.GetEnumerable();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Animal a = (Animal)enumerator.Current;
            Console.WriteLine(a.AnimalType);
        }
    }
}
```

First question: Why I got no output, and Main simply returns?
Second question: Why did the casting from `IEnumerable<Animal>` to `IEnumerator<Animal>` didn't issue compiling error?

Comment: You should use `farm.GetEnumerable().GetEnumerator()` instead of casting

Comment: The cast is allowed because the object returned from `GetEnumerable()` could implement both `IEnumerable<Animal>` and `IEnumerator<Animal>`. If you want an underlying enumerator you should call `GetEnumerator()` on it.

Comment: The cast is allowed, but changing the code to `farm.GetEnumerable().GetEnumerator();` does fix the problem.  I don't know why, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how your `FarmCollection.GetEnumerable` method looks like when it is decompiled:

```
public IEnumerable<Animal> GetEnumerable()
{
    FarmCollection.<GetEnumerable>d__0 <GetEnumerable>d__ =
        new FarmCollection.<GetEnumerable>d__0(-2);
    <GetEnumerable>d__.<>4__this = this;
    return <GetEnumerable>d__;
}
```

The type `FarmCollection.<GetEnumerable>d__0` is also generated by the compiler. See [this article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) for more details. Here is how this class looks like:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <GetEnumerable>d__0 : IEnumerable<Animal>, IEnumerable, IEnumerator<Animal>, IEnumerator, IDisposable
{
    private Animal <>2__current;

    private int <>1__state;

    private int <>l__initialThreadId;

    public FarmCollection <>4__this;

    public Animal <a>5__1;

    public Animal[] <>7__wrap3;

    public int <>7__wrap4;

    Animal IEnumerator<Animal>.Current
    {
        [DebuggerHidden]
        get
        {
            return this.<>2__current;
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        [DebuggerHidden]
        get
        {
            return this.<>2__current;
        }
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    IEnumerator<Animal> IEnumerable<Animal>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        FarmCollection.<GetEnumerable>d__0 <GetEnumerable>d__;
        if (Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId == this.<>l__initialThreadId && this.<>1__state == -2)
        {
            this.<>1__state = 0;
            <GetEnumerable>d__ = this;
        }
        else
        {
            <GetEnumerable>d__ = new FarmCollection.<GetEnumerable>d__0(0);
            <GetEnumerable>d__.<>4__this = this.<>4__this;
        }
        return <GetEnumerable>d__;
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ConsoleApplication479.Animal>.GetEnumerator();
    }

    bool IEnumerator.MoveNext()
    {
        bool result;
        try
        {
            switch (this.<>1__state)
            {
            case 0:
                this.<>1__state = -1;
                this.<>1__state = 1;
                this.<>7__wrap3 = this.<>4__this._farm;
                this.<>7__wrap4 = 0;
                goto IL_8D;
            case 2:
                this.<>1__state = 1;
                this.<>7__wrap4++;
                goto IL_8D;
            }
            goto IL_A9;
            IL_8D:
            if (this.<>7__wrap4 < this.<>7__wrap3.Length)
            {
                this.<a>5__1 = this.<>7__wrap3[this.<>7__wrap4];
                this.<>2__current = this.<a>5__1;
                this.<>1__state = 2;
                result = true;
                return result;
            }
            this.<>m__Finally2();
            IL_A9:
            result = false;
        }
        catch
        {
            this.System.IDisposable.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
        return result;
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    void IEnumerator.Reset()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        switch (this.<>1__state)
        {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            return;
        }
        this.<>m__Finally2();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public <GetEnumerable>d__0(int <>1__state)
    {
        this.<>1__state = <>1__state;
        this.<>l__initialThreadId = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId;
    }

    private void <>m__Finally2()
    {
        this.<>1__state = -1;
    }
}
```

So in your code, the `enumerator` variable refers to an object of this type. Since this type implements `IEnumerator<Animal>`, this explains why the cast did not fail.

Now, to your second question. Notice that the `GetEnumerable` method generated by the compiler constructs the `FarmCollection.<GetEnumerable>d__0` instance and gives the value `-2` to the constructor. This is stored in the `<>1__state` variable. Now, take a look at the `MoveNext()` method. It has a switch statement over the `<>1__state` variable. If the value of such variable is not `0` or `2`, then the method is guaranteed to return `false` which means that no values would be returned from the enumeration.

Notice how the `GetEnumerator()` method in this class changes the state to 0 and returns the same instance (in some case, it returns a new instance of the class with state 0) which would make the `MoveNext` method work.

So basically the `MoveNext` method will not work without executing `GetEnumerator()`.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, what tool did you use to display the generated code in such a convenient way?

Comment: You're welcome. I use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/). Just make sure to uncheck the "decompile enumerators (yield return)" checkbox from View -> Options.

Comment: Great, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [de-sugared code](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#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), you can see that using `yield return` will create an inner class that implements both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>`. That's why the cast is valid.

The important line is in the method GetEnumerable():
It returns `new FarmCollection.<GetEnumerable>d__1(-2);`

So, the initial state is -2, the "No-one-has-requested-an-Enumerator-yet state". If you call `GetEnumerator()` it will set its state to 0, the "start of enumeration state".
But since you are not calling `GetEnumerator()`, its state will remain -2 and therefore, when `MoveNext()` checks the state, it will see -2 and return false.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't familiar with the Try Roslyn, so thank you for that, too.